# Add ID into map in Future function

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that fetches some data from my firestore database, but because at some point I also want to push data to the collection I also need the ID of the document. When I had the function below, all was fine and the function was returning a Future.

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getTours(String uid) async {
    final userToursQuerySnapshot =
        await accounts.doc(uid).collection('tours').get();

    return userToursQuerySnapshot.docs.map((userTourQueryDocumentSnapshot) =>
        userTourQueryDocumentSnapshot.data()
    ).toList();
  }
```

However, when switching to the function below, I get an error that it's returning a List, and not a Future anymore.

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getTours(String uid) async {
    final userToursQuerySnapshot =
        await accounts.doc(uid).collection('tours').get();

    return userToursQuerySnapshot.docs.map((userTourQueryDocumentSnapshot) {
      Map userTourData = userTourQueryDocumentSnapshot.data();
      userTourData['tourID'] = userTourQueryDocumentSnapshot.id;
      return userTourData;
    }).toList();
  }
```

I kind of want to keep the Future, because it allows me to display a loading bubble on the screen where it's being displayed. Is there a better way?

Comment: What is the exact error message?  It's not possible for your second version to *not* return a `Future`.  One questionable thing is that you declare `Map userTourData = ...`, but that declares `userTourData` to be a `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`.  It's instead better to use `var userTourData = ...` and let `userTourData`'s type be inferred from the right-hand-side.